# Lipschitz-continuous $f(x)=x^2\cdot \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions, holder-spaces

How to prove that $f$ is globally
Lipschitz-continuous $$ f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

$$ f(x) = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{c l}
    x^2\cdot \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) & ,\quad x\neq0\\
    0 & ,\quad x=0
  \end{array} \right.$$

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Notice that
$$
f'(x)=\begin{cases}
2x\sin\frac1x-\cos\frac1x &\text{ if } x\ne0\\
0 &\text{ if } x=0
\end{cases}.
$$
Therefore
$$
|f'(x)|\le 2|x|\cdot\left|\sin\frac1x\right|+\left|\cos\frac1x\right|\le 3 \quad \forall x\ne 0.
$$
Hence,
$$
|f'(x)|\le 3 \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}.
$$
It follows that 
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|\le \sup_{\min\{x,y\} \le z\le \max\{x,y\}}|f'(z)||x-y|\le 3|x-y| \quad \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}.
$$

Comment: It may cost more paper to estimate  $f'(x)$,but I'm sure it's bounded.

Comment: @CWeid Not really. $x\sin x^{-1}$ is bounded above and below by $1$. This is easy to see if you write any nonzero $x\in\Bbb R$ as $1/t$ and observe $t^{-1}\sin t$ is bounded by $1$ in absolute value.

Comment: @mathematics2x2life Not true. The function is uniformly continuous. As I said above $|t^{-1}\sin t|\leqslant 1$. Then write $t=x^{-1}$. It follows that $|f'|\leqslant 3$, as Mercy correctly estimated.