# If $f$ is differentiable on $[a, b]$, is $f$ Lipschitz of order $1$ on $[a, b]$?

Tags: calculus

> If $f$ is differentiable on $[a, b]$, is $f$ Lipschitz of order $1$ on $[a, b]$?

The author puts the following function as a counterexample, but I don't understand why.
$$f(x)= \begin{cases} x^2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right), & \text{if }  x\neq 0,\\ 0, & \text{if } x=0, \end{cases}$$ on $[0,1]$. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: But could be done
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^2 \sin\frac{1}{x^2}\qquad x\neq 0\\
0\qquad\quad\qquad x=0
\end{cases}
$$
It is differentiable on $[0,1]$ and
$$
f'(x)=
\begin{cases}
2 x \sin\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{2}{x} \cos\frac{1}{x^2},  &x\neq 0\\
0,  &x=0
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: If the function was Lipschitz, its derivative would be bounded on $[0,1]$, but it is not. The derivative should be continuous on $[0,1]$ in order to satisfy the Lipschitz condition.

Comment: If I understand that, it was an error of the author, but then I don't know how to continue to conclude that it is not of order 1

Comment: Show that if $f$ was Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant $L$, then $|f'(x)|\leq L$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. (Hint re-order the Lipschitz condition and let $y\to x$)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3043139/prove-fx-x2-sin-left-frac1x-right-is-lipschitz-no-use-of-derivativ